# Linking and sorting arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So, I'm pretty new to programming (I started a month ago) and I recently started learning arrays and sorting. For homework, I got an assignment to make three arrays (name, place of residence and amount of money) and then to have the program print out the name, place of residence and amount of money a person has as well as sort them according to the amount of money they have. I hope that makes sense. So far, I was only able to have to program sort the amount of money from biggest to smallest but I don't know how to link the array with numbers to the other two arrays so that it prints everything properly.

So for example, I have:

```
String[] Names = {"Person","Human","Man","Woman"};
String[] Adress = {"Hole","Street","Attic","Room"};
int[] Money = {25,0,12,13};
```

And instead of it printing out:

```
Person 
Hole 
25
Woman 
Room 
13
Man 
Attic 
12
Human 
Hole 
0
```

It just prints out:

```
Person 
Hole
25
Human
Street
13
Man
Attic
12
Woman
Room
0
```

I hope some can help. I tried figuring out on my own but I rly stuck.
Thank u

Also here is the code that I have so far:

```
package practice;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Try {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] Names = {"Person","Human","Man","Woman"};
        String[] Adress = {"Hole","Street","Attic","Room"};
        int[] Money = {25,0,12,13};


            int first, current, least, temp;

            for(first=0;first<4;first++){
              least=first;
              for(current=first+1;current<4;current++){
                if (Money[current]>Money[least]){
                  least=current;
                }
                temp=Money[least];
                Money[least]=Money[first];
                Money[first]=temp;
              }
            }


            for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
              System.out.println(Names[i]);
              System.out.println(Adress[i]);
              System.out.println(Money[i]);
            }
          }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sorting algorithm, you are already working with indices (`first`, `least` and `current`). When you use them to swap two elements of the `Money` array here:

```java
temp=Money[least];
Money[least]=Money[first];
Money[first]=temp;
```

just do the same for the other two arrays. The best thing to do would be writing a [generic](https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics) method for it so you do not have to write unnecessarily redundant code. However, since you are very new to coding, let's just not do this yet. One possible solution could look like this:

```java
package practice;

public class Try {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] names = {"Person", "Human", "Man", "Woman"};
        String[] adress = {"Hole", "Street", "Attic", "Room"};
        int[] money = {25, 0, 12, 13};

        for(int first = 0; first < 4; first++){
            int most = first;
            for(int current = first + 1; current < 4; current++){
                if (money[current] > money[most]){
                    most = current;
                }
                int temp = money[most];
                money[most] = money[first];
                money[first] = temp;

                String tempString = names[most];
                names[most] = names[first];
                names[first] = tempString;

                tempString = adress[most];
                adress[most] = adress[first];
                adress[first] = tempString;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            System.out.println(names[i]);
            System.out.println(adress[i]);
            System.out.println(money[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

(I took the liberty of cleaning up your code a bit.)

Last but not least, there are still many ways to write cleaner and more structured and optimised code and what not. But since your assignment is about understanding very basic concepts of Java and coding in general, this approach should do the trick just fine for now. Just one thing about [Java naming conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions): class names start with an uppercase letter whereas methods and variables start with a lowercase letter. The compiler will not complain if you do not stick to it but the code will become less readable since you never know if e.g. `Money` is a variable or a class.

Answer (score 1):

I think what is lacking in your solution is the "link" between your arrays. 
I will explain my solution. You add a new array that is equivalent to your Money array and having the indexes of each element from 0 to 3.

For element 0, you have Person Hole 25

For element 1, you have Human Street 0
etc...

The Link array's goal is to preserve the link between the money and the element.
So when the algorithm sorts the Money array, it will permut the indexes accordingly to preserve the link.

For example, Human has less money (0) than Man (12) so we are going to permut between 0 and 12 but to not lose their indexes we also permut 1 and 2 that are Link[1] and Link[2] and that are equivalent to Human and Man. So in the end, when we print out, we will print the money array elements nd refer to the name and the address contained within the link array elements that are still linking between the three tables.
I hope you understood what I was talking about, maybe I talked a lot.

```
public class Try {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] Names = {"Person","Human","Man","Woman"};
        String[] Adress = {"Hole","Street","Attic","Room"};
        int[] Money = {25,0,12,13};

        int[] Link = {0,1,2,3};

           int first, current, least, temp;

            for(first=0;first<4;first++){
              least=first;
              for(current=first+1;current<4;current++){
                if (Money[current]>Money[least]){
                  least=current;
                }
                temp=Money[least];
                Money[least]=Money[first];
                Money[first]=temp;

                temp=Link[least];
                Link[least]=Link[first];
                Link[first]=temp;


              }
            }


            for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
              System.out.println(Names[Link[i]]);
              System.out.println(Adress[Link[i]]);
              System.out.println(Money[i]);
            }
          }




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: inside the nested for loops that swap elements of the money array, do you think you could swap other elements as well?

```
temp=Money[least];
Money[least]=Money[first];
Money[first]=temp;
```

In programming it helps to draw out things on a sheet of paper when it gets confusing, and keep track of all the different variables as you work your way through the code. Try writing out your arrays, and seeing what happens as you step through each line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Just use any sorting to sort Money and while swapping Money element swap both Names and Address array element

```
            String[] Names = {"Person","Human","Man","Woman"};
            String[] Address = {"Hole","Street","Attic","Room"};
            int[] Money = {25,0,12,13};

            int n = Money.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) {
                    if (Money[j] < Money[j+1])
                    {
                        // swap Money array element
                        int temp = Money[j];
                        Money[j] = Money[j+1];
                        Money[j+1] = temp;

                        // swap Names array element
                        String tempName = Names[j];
                        Names[j] = Names[j+1];
                        Names[j+1] = tempName;

                        // swap Address array element
                        String tempAddress = Address[j];
                        Address[j] = Address[j+1];
                        Address[j+1] = tempAddress;


                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < Money.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(Names[i]);
                System.out.println(Address[i]);
                System.out.println(Money[i]);
            }
```